# Elementary OS, add custom command in context menu pantheon-files

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files, pantheon-terminal

I am trying to add a custom item to the pantheon-files context menu. When you click on a menu item in a folder, the terminal should start and process several commands, and thumbnail files should be created in the same folder at the output. I have next code in `/usr/share/contractor/thumbnail.contract` :

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Создать миниатюры изображений [500px]
Description=Make thumbnails
Icon=terminal
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=io.elementary.terminal for file in *.jpg; do convert -scale 500 $file tn_$file ; done
Gettext-Domain=io.elementary.terminal
```

Unfortunately it does not work( 
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend putting custom contracts in `~/.local/share/contractor`.

If you do not need terminal to open then this works:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Создать миниатюры изображений [500px]
Description=Make thumbnails
Icon=terminal
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=sh -c 'cd %U; for file in *.jpg; do convert -scale 500 $file tn_$file ; done;'
Gettext-Domain=sh
```

You can get terminal to open as well by appending `io.elementary.terminal;` to the shell command